# How to pass django error status to ajax

Tags: ajax, django, rest, backbone.js, error-handling

Using django rest framework with backbone.

**Current situation:**
Whenever an `ajax` call fails, django responds through  `get_error_response`
As soon as `get_error_response` gets invoked, django raises a error on client side too, as i am not handling this error in django(server) side.

**`views.py` snippet**

```
 def get_error_response(self):
    return Response(
        self.serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    )
```

**Requirement:**
I want to be able to pass all error statuses to `$ajax.fail()` promise, and handle it there on client side, thereby enabling me to show the error messages to user.

*Note:something like the code given below is what i am expecting. But the problem is, this response would got to `$ajax.done` promise(), wheras i want it in `$ajax.fail()` promise*

```
 def get_error_response(self):
    return Response({
        "msg":self.serializer.errors, "error_status":status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    })
```

Do ask if more clarity is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter if you're using a `Response` from Django Rest Framework or the normal Django `HttpResponse` you always need to pass the keyworded argument `status` in order to make the response actually have the correct status code thus invoking the correct handler in your front end code.

What your last example does is only passing a `data` or `content` argument which is making the response class default to a `200` status code.

```
return Response(your_data, status=404)
```

Comment: But then how should i pass this status to client side so that, `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/ 400 (BAD REQUEST)` error can be stopped being raised from server side, and show better error messages in client side

Comment: This will always/should invoke the `fail` handler.